# Joining Strings on New Lines Error Python

Tags: python, string, list

Almost there with this one!

Taking user input and removing any trailing punctuation and non-hashed words to spot trends in tweets. Don't ask!

```
tweet = input('Tweet: ')
tweets = ''

while tweet != '':
  tweets += tweet
  tweet = input('Tweet: ')

print (tweets) # only using this to spot where things are going wrong!

listed_tweets = tweets.lower().rstrip('\'\"-,.:;!?').split(' ')
hashed = []

for entry in listed_tweets:
  if entry[0] == '#':
    hashed.append(entry) 

from collections import Counter
trend = Counter(hashed)

for item in trend:
  print (item, trend[item])
```

Which works apart from that fact I get:

```
Tweet: #Python is #AWESOME!
Tweet: This is #So_much_fun #awesome
Tweet: 
#Python is #AWESOME!This is #So_much_fun #awesome
#awesome!this 1
#python 1
#so_much_fun 1
#awesome 1
```

Instead of:

```
#so_much_fun 1 
#awesome 2
#python 1
```

So I'm not getting a space at the end of each line of input and it's throwing my list!

It's probably very simple, but after 10hrs straight of self-teaching, my mind is mush!!

Comment: If all you want is a space, so you could later split them spaces, why don't you simply write `tweets += tweet + ' '`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
  tweets += tweet
```

You're taking each tweet and appending it to the previous one. Thus, the last word of the previous tweet gets joined with the first word of the current tweet.

There are various ways to solve this problem. One approach is to process the tweets one at a time. Start out with an empty array for your hashtags, then do the following in a loop:

1. read a line from the user
2. if the line is empty, break out of the loop
3. otherwise, extract the hashtags and add them to the array
4. return to step 1

The following code incorporates this idea and makes several other improvements. Notice how the interactive loop is written so that there's only one place in the code where we prompt the user for input.

```
hashtags = []

while True:                      # Read and clean each line of input.
  tweet = input('Tweet: ').lower().rstrip('\'\"-,.:;!?')
  if tweet == '':                # Check for empty input.
    break 
  print('cleaned tweet: '+tweet) # Review the cleaned tweet.
  for word in tweet.split():     # Extract hashtags.
    if word[0] == '#':
      hashtags.append(word)

from collections import Counter
trend = Counter(hashtags)

for item in trend:
  print (item, trend[item])
```

If you continue working on tweet processing, I suspect that you'll find that your tweet-cleaning process is inadequate. What if there is punctuation in the middle of a tweet, for example? You will probably want to embark on the study of regular expressions sooner or later.